# Idiomatic way to create a spark context with a default master

Tags: apache-spark

Is there an idiomatic way to create a spark context, that if no other master is provided will default to some fall back master?

e.g.

```
new SparkContext(defaultMaster = "local[4]")
```

If I run this with let's say, spark-submit and specify a master as a CLI param, or via an env variable, it will use that, but if I run it without specifying anything, it will default to what I provided above.

Is there a built in way to achieve this? (I have workarounds but I was wondering if there is a common pattern for this behavior)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[4]")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the default master url in **`conf/spark-defaults.conf`** in the Spark directory
or 
Use :

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[4]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

And whenever you set master url using **--master** it overrides the default values.